# doxygen default layout.xml is 25Mb. Is it normal?

Tags: doxygen

subj
I generated it using:

```
doxygen -l defaultLayout.xml
```

When try to open in the Notepad++, I see
[image]

I looked in the CGAl sources. Their custom layout file is 6Kb and opens normal.

Comment: This definitely not normal, should be around 6Kb. Which version of doxygen are you using (doxygen -v) and on which platform? What happens if you run doxygen normally or try to output other types of files (header / footer / configuration file)?

Comment: version: 1.8.9.1. Generation of other types of files is normal.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Is the executable a pre-compiled or a self compiled executable?

Comment: Windows 7. I downloaded doxygen installer package from the official site.

Comment: Very strange as I use Windows 7 as well and I also have this version (besides a number of other versions). Looks like a system depended problem. Did you check if there is not another problem with the system or with Notepad++, do you get the same when you do a "more" on the file? I assume you did try  to run the doxygen command from the command line in different directories and that you tried to reinstall doxygen (after a fresh download).

Comment: I tried on 2 PCs install package & zip-archives(32 & 64 bit). The problem still exists :D

Comment: Beats me. I'll try on some other computers as well.